# Why is my Meteor app reloading every page when click navigation link?

Tags: meteor

This is really confusing to me. I am trying to do something very basic.

I have Iron-Router installed and I am just trying to navigate between pages. But it looks like Meteor is reloading the page each time instead of just re-rendering the new page in the yield spot.

So I have a layout file header and a sidebar template, and a yield template.

In the sidebar I use the pathFor helpers to fill in the target href when clicking a link. For example:

```
  ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked       
    li.active
      a(href='{{pathFor "dashboard"}}', title='Manage Users')
        i.icon-speedometer
        |  Users
    li
      a(href='{{pathFor "adminFarms"}}', title='Farms')
        i.icon-speedometer 
        |  Farms
```

But the problem is when navigating between those 2 links, Meteor reloads the whole page! Why is this, I feel like I have done this many times in Meteor apps and it just loads the new page in the yield spot. But this time it keeps reloading the whole layout! What is going on, this is so simple yet I don't understand.

Also I cant intercept the click as well. For some strange reason when I add an id to the a link and try and target it in the Template.template.events handler, I can't seem to get it to console.log anything. How come I cannot intercept an event for an a link in Meteor.

**UPDATE:**

If I remove the class .nav .nav-pills & .nav-stacked from the un-ordered list tag then it works normally. So the issue must be with bootstrap somehow interfering with Meteor single page app functionality. Any clue as to what is going on?

**UPDATE 2**
Found the issue! It was a package that was included in the theme I was using for multi-level menus. The package is Navgoco, and it was intercepting all the events on anything with the .nav class.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this event handler.

```
Template.dashboard.events({ 
  'click a':function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
})
```

Comment: No this is not the solution. The problem is the event handler is not even called no matter what I do. This is not a preventDefault issue. Meteor should automatically pickup on the link and load the new page without reloading the layout. The issue is that the event handler is not even being called at all. I figured out that there is some issue with bootstrap and meteor or something

Comment: are you using famo package?

Comment: nope, not using famo.us. Everything seems to work when I don't use bootstrap .nav .nav-stacked & .nav-pills class on the unordered list. Once I remove the classes on the <ul> element, the <a> links inside the <li> now works without reloading the page. As soon as I add those classes back, then it stops working.

Comment: I am using mizzao's package: mizzao:bootstrap-3. Should I replace it with another bootstrap package, could this be the issue?

Comment: im pretty sure you have another .css using the same class or causing conflict on the project, component.css or something try removing all css from project and just keep mizao and make a try

Comment: Ah I got it. It was the Navgoco plugin I was using. Not a meteor package but it was a js file that is part of the theme I was using. This was for multi-level nav menu. Navgoco was intercepting all the events and meteor router could not get to it. Thank so much for your help, it helped me narrow in on the problem